# How to disable right click on a menu in javafx

Tags: javafx, menu

In javaFX code, a menu can popup by left click or right click. How to disable right click?

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

    Menu hello = new Menu("hello");
    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(hello);
    Menu world = new Menu("world");
    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(world);
    root.setCenter(menuBar);

    MenuItem item = new MenuItem("laugh");
    hello.getItems().add(item);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

When I right click the "hello" menu, it will popup menuitem "laugh".

Comment: On face value, the solution is to register an eventFilter for mousePressed on the menuBar and consume the event if secondary button is pressed. Gets a bit more involved, if you need to disable the right click for menuItems, that is not fire the action then. The approach is the same (eventFilter that consumes) but getting hold of the contextMenus is tricky - walking the menu hierarchy could be possible but the menus are re-created often. Probably best to implement a custom ContextMenuSkin that adds the eventFilter to its root and make that the default via a stylesheet - didn't try, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic approach is to register a eventFilter on the MenuBar that consumes the events that should not be delivered to the children.

Doing so manually in your application code:

```
public class DisableRightClickOpenMenu extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

        menuBar.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, ev -> {
            if (ev.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                ev.consume();
            }
        });

        Menu hello = new Menu("hello");
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(hello);
        Menu world = new Menu("world");
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(world);
        root.setCenter(menuBar);

        MenuItem item = new MenuItem("laugh");
        hello.getItems().add(item);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

If you want this behaviour across all your applications, you can implement a custom menuBarSkin that registers the filter and install the custom skin via a stylesheet.

The skin:

```
public class ExMenuBarSkin extends MenuBarSkin {

    /**
     * Instantiates a skin for the given MenuBar. Registers an
     * event filter that consumes right mouse press.
     *  
     * @param menuBar
     */
    public ExMenuBarSkin(MenuBar menuBar) {
        super(menuBar);
        menuBar.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, ev -> {
            if (ev.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                ev.consume();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

In your stylesheet (replace with your fully qualified class name):

```
.menu-bar {
     -fx-skin: "de.swingempire.fx.event.ExMenuBarSkin";

}
```

Its usage (replace the name with your stylesheet file name):

```
URL uri = getClass().getResource("contextskin.css");
primaryStage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(uri.toExternalForm());
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find that the event filter can be added in a menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

This is usual behavior of menu in many programs. I don't think you can change it. However, you can use some other controls and simulate menu. (Like `HBox` and `Label`s).

Comment: when you right click a windows menu, it will not respond. I just want the javafx menu to be like a windows menu.

Comment: I didn't pay attention which programs have one or another kind of menus - but plenty of them doesn't makes difference which mouse button is clicked (even a middle button).

Comment: for example, the explorer menu. when you visit your harddisk. the window's menu cannot popup by right click

Comment: You're right, but I don't see the way to do this with Javafx `MenuBar`. As I said, you CAN use some other controls and write the proper `ActionListener`s (mouse events). Good luck.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18622843)

Comment: @fantaghirocco I'm aware of that. I accidentally clicked on the "answer" ... Now is too late to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree as far as I know there's no a standard way to do this, but you may want to consider the following workaround.

It is replacing the Menu node with a Menu object composed by an HBox and a Label: an EventHandler is added to the HBox and by checking the mouse button pressed we add/remove on the fly the MenuItem to its parent.

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
    final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    final MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    final Menu menuHello = new Menu();
    final Menu menuWorld = new Menu("world");
    final MenuItem menuitem = new MenuItem("laugh");
    final HBox hbox = new HBox();

    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menuHello, menuWorld);

    root.setCenter(menuBar);

    hbox.setPrefWidth(30);
    hbox.getChildren().add(new Label("hello"));

    menuHello.setGraphic(hbox);
    menuHello.getItems().add(menuitem);

    hbox.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(final MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                System.out.println("Right click");
                menuHello.getItems().remove(menuitem);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Left click");
                if (!menuHello.getItems().contains(menuitem)) {
                    menuHello.getItems().add(menuitem);
                    menuHello.show(); // The .show method prevent 'losing' the current click                    }
            }
        }
    });

    final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

This will produce the following result - [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiXx1.gif)

Note that I've used an HBox just for habit, there's no a particular reason.

While using a workaround like this, my suggestion would be to fill all the Menus with the same 'pattern', such as the HBox + Label combo in my example, and stylize them via css/code (width/height, background/fill/hover... colors etc.) in order to have them as uniform as possible and avoid creating graphic inconsistencies due to have different nodes types in the same menubar.